# get current user in form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

im trying to get current login user in form field using ForeignKey , but im  getting dropdown menu with list all users in database

view.py

```
@login_required
def user_request(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRequest(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.save(commit=False)
            data.user = request.user
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Success')
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = UserRequest()
        print(form)
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, 'users/request.html', context)
```

models.py

```
class UserRequestModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_id = models.FloatField()
    email = models.EmailField()
    status = models.CharField(default='Pending', max_length=20)
    date = models.DateField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

form.py

```
class UserRequestForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserRequestModel
        fields = ['user']


class UserRequest(UserRequestForm):
    date = forms.DateField()
    product_id = forms.IntegerField()

    class Meta(UserRequestForm.Meta):
        fields = UserRequestForm.Meta.fields + ['date', 'product_id']
```

what im missing to get current user in form field instead of all users list?

Comment: If you do not use current user information, remove that field from the form. You can also check documentation to where you need to handle this process: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user

Comment: i want to use current user (thats the main point) , but getting all user list instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ModelForm docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types) show that the default field type for a ForeignKey is [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField), which renders a `<select>` in your HTML. This allows the selection of a single model object.

If you want to keep the `<select>` with all users and have the current user pre-selected, you can do this in your view by passing in an [initial value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values):

```py
# Bound form
form = UserRequest(request.POST or None, initial={'user': request.user})
# Unbound form
form = UserRequest(initial={'user': request.user})
```

If you instead want the form field to be something else (like a plain HTML `<input>`) with a value of the current user id, you will need to pass in an initial value as above, and also [change the default widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) in your `forms.py`:

```py
class UserRequest(UserRequestForm):
    date = forms.DateField()
    product_id = forms.IntegerField()

    class Meta(UserRequestForm.Meta):
        fields = UserRequestForm.Meta.fields + ['date', 'product_id']
        widgets = {
            'user': forms.TextInput(),
        }
```